# Facebook JS SDK: Create event on a page (not a profile)

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I’m using Facebook’s JavaScript SDK to do something like

```
FB.api('/1234567890/events', 'POST', {
    name: "My cute test event",
    start_time: 1313161200,
    end_time: 1313531700,
    location: "Over the Rainbow"
}, function (res) {
    // whatever
});
```

to create an event on a Facebook page. The user who is authenticated is an admin of that page 1234567890 and gave `manage_pages` and `create_event` permissions.

However, the event created does not belong to the page, but is instead created as an event of the authenticated user and thus only shows up in his friends’ stream, but not on the page specified.

How can I fix that?

I know that there is the `/me/accounts` API call that returns access tokens to do API calls on behalf of the user’s pages, but I don’t see where in Facebook’s JavaScript SDK I could actually change the access token.

(And yes, I know that creating events using Unix timestamps is bad. I’ll fix that as well, but I guess it doesn’t have anything to do with this problem.)

Comment: Are you sure that your page is 1234567890 and not your own fbuser id??Use the api explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and i checked it with enhanced permissions, its working.

Comment: you can just append the access_token for the pages as a argument with the api call itself.. Like `FB.api('/1234567890/events?access_token=xxxxxxx', 'POST', {.......`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *Vijay* for pointing me in the right direction (not in an answer, though):

You can set the `access_token` by adding it to the object you’re passing to the POST, e.g.:

```
FB.api('/1234567890/events', 'POST', {
    access_token: "152770078124166|2.AQBX…",
    name: "My cute test event",
    start_time: 1313161200,
    end_time: 1313531700,
    location: "Over the Rainbow"
}, function (res) {
    // whatever
});
```

Adding the `access_token` to the end of the URL did however not work, because then the SDK will supply Facebook with both your custom token (as a query string parameter) and its default token (as a POST parameter), and Facebook seems to prefer the POST `access_token` (or choose them kind of randomly, which is about as bad).